# How to achieve that JSON structure in PHP

Tags: php, json, pdo

For an autocomplete-plugin, I need to generate a JSON-structure like that:

> {"tags":[{"tag":"Pisa"},{"tag":"Rome"},{"tag":"Milan"},{"tag":"Florence"},{"tag":"New York"},{"tag":"Paris"},{"tag":"Berlin"},{"tag":"London"},{"tag":"Madrid"}]}

I tried with the following PHP-code:

```
$tags = array();
while (($row = $statement -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== false) {
    $tags[] = array('tag' => $row['text']);
}
echo json_encode($tags);
```

but that generates only

> [{"tag":"Pisa"},{"tag":"Rome"},{"tag":"Milan"},{"tag":"Florence"},{"tag":"New York"},{"tag":"Paris"},{"tag":"Berlin"},{"tag":"London"},{"tag":"Madrid"}]

so the wrapping "tags" is missing - how do I achieve that properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$tags = array();
while (($row = $statement -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== false) {
    $tags[] = array('tag' => $row['text']);
}
echo json_encode(array('tags'=> $tags));
```

You must just set your tags array in other array with key 'tags' ..

Answer (score 2):

```
return json_encode(array('tags' => $statement->fetchAll()));
```

(of course you need to `select text as tag` in your query. and set `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` as a default fetch option, to make your code meaningful and DRY)